# Access DBからMySQL DBへのエクスポート

Tags: mysql, ms-access

Access DBからMySQL ODBCを使用して、MySQLへのエクスポートをしようとしています。

MS Accessでテーブルを選択して、エクスポート → ODBC データベースを選択し、
実行すると、

ODBC － 呼び出しが失敗しました。
　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Incorrect string value ....

と表示されて、エクスポートができません。

文字コードの指定がどこか、おかしいのだろうと思うのですが、原因が掴めないでいます。

AccessのDBの文字コードは SJISです。
MySQLの文字コードもSJISにしたつもりです。my.iniの設定は以下のようになっています。

[mysql]
default-character-set=sjis

[mysqld]
default-character-set=sjis

どこを修正すればいいのか、教えて頂けないでしょうか。

以上。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/35722

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qiita.com/shinyaYS/items/0f9e4c7beaa036608075

Comment: マルチポスト　http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q12159685332

Comment: マルチポスト　http://qa.atmarkit.co.jp/q/9924

Answer (score 1):

MySQL の sjis には Windows でよく使われるいわゆる機種依存文字(「①」「㈱」とか)が入ってないので、sjis ではなく cp932 を使ってみるのが良いと思います。

Comment: MySQLをcp932にする件は試してみました。
やはり、文字コードのエラーが出ていました。
エクスポート元のAccessがSJISなのですが、MySQLの文字コードをcp932にして、エクスポートできるのでしょうか？

Comment: MySQL の sjis と cp932 は同じコード系で、cp932 の方が収録文字数が多いという感じなので、問題ないはずです。
エラーメッセージを正確に示したほうが回答が得られやすいと思います。